# Efficient way to calculate distance function

Tags: fortran, euclidean-distance

I have a 3D matrix (dimension nx,nz,ny) which corresponds to a physical domain. This matrix contains a continuous field from -1 (phase 1) to +1 (phase 2); the interface between the two phases is the level 0 of this field.

Now, I want to calculate efficiently the signed distance function from the interface for every point in the domain.

I tried two possibilities (sgn is the sign of my field, with values +1,0,-1, xyz contains the grid as triplets of x,y,z at each point and dist is the signed distance function I want to calculate).

```
double precision, dimension(nx,nz,ny) :: dist,sgn,eudist
integer :: i,j,k
double precision :: seed,posit,tmp(nx)

do j=1,ny  
do k=1,nz  
 do i=1,nx  
  seed=sgn(i,k,j)  
    ! look for interface  
    eudist=(xyz(:,:,:,1)-x(i))**2+(xyz(:,:,:,2)-z(k))**2+(xyz(:,:,:,3)-y(j))**2  
    ! find min within mask  
    posit=minval(eudist,seed*sgn.le.0)  
    ! tmp fits in cache, small speed-up  
    tmp(i)=-seed*dsqrt(posit)  
  enddo  
  dist(:,k,j)=tmp  
enddo  
enddo
```

I also tried a second version, which is quite similar to the above one but it calculates the Euclidean distance only in a subset of the whole matrix. With this second version there is some speed up, but it is still too slow. I would like to know whether there is a more efficient way to calculate the distance function.

Second version:

```
double precision, dimension(nx,nz,ny) :: dist,sgn
double precision, allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: eudist
integer :: i,j,k  , ii,jj,kk
integer :: il,iu,jl,ju,kl,ku
double precision :: seed, deltax,deltay,deltaz,tmp(nx)

deltax=max(int(nx/4),1)
deltay=max(int(ny/4),1)
deltaz=max(int(nz/2),1)

allocate(eudist(2*deltax+1,2*deltaz+1,2*deltay+1))

do j=1,ny
 do k=1,nz
  do i=1,nx
   ! look for closest point in box 2*deltax+1,2*deltaz+1,2*deltay+1
   il=max(1,i-deltax)
   iu=min(nx,i+deltax)
   jl=max(1,j-deltay)
   ju=min(ny,j+deltay)
   kl=max(1,k-deltaz)
   ku=min(nz,k+deltaz)

   eudist(:,1:ku-kl+1,:)=(xyz(il:iu,kl:ku,jl:ju,1)-x(i))**2 &
 &                      +(xyz(il:iu,kl:ku,jl:ju,2)-z(k))**2 &
 &                      +(xyz(il:iu,kl:ku,jl:ju,3)-y(j))**2

   seed=sgn(i,k,j)
   tmp(i)=minval(eudist(:,1:ku-kl+1,:),seed*sgn(il:iu,kl:ku,jl:ju).le.0)
   tmp(i)=-seed*dsqrt(tmp(i))

  enddo
  dist(:,k,j)=tmp
 enddo
enddo
```

eudist: Euclidean distance between the point i,k,j and any other point in a box 2*deltax+1,2*deltaz+1,2*deltay+1 centered in i,k,j. This reduces computational cost, as the distance is calculated only in a subset of the whole grid (here I am assuming that the subset is large enough to contain an interfacial point).

After Vladimir suggestion (x,y,z are the axes determining grid position, xyz(i,k,j)=(x(i),z(k),y(j)) ):

```
double precision, dimension(nx,nz,ny) :: dist,sgn
double precision :: x(nx), y(ny), z(nz)
double precision, allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: eudist
double precision, allocatable, dimension(:) :: xd,yd,zd
integer :: i,j,k  , ii,jj,kk
integer :: il,iu,jl,ju,kl,ku
double precision :: seed, deltax,deltay,deltaz,tmp(nx)

deltax=max(int(nx/4),1)
deltay=max(int(ny/4),1)
deltaz=max(int(nz/2),1)

allocate(eudist(2*deltax+1,2*deltaz+1,2*deltay+1))
allocate(xd(2*deltax+1))
allocate(yd(2*deltay+1))
allocate(zd(2*deltaz+1))

do j=1,ny
 do k=1,nz
  do i=1,nx
   ! look for closest point in box 2*deltax+1,2*deltaz+1,2*deltay+1
   il=max(1,i-deltax)
   iu=min(nx,i+deltax)
   jl=max(1,j-deltay)
   ju=min(ny,j+deltay)
   kl=max(1,k-deltaz)
   ku=min(nz,k+deltaz)

   do ii=1,iu-il+1
     xd(ii)=(xyz(il+ii-1)-x(i))**2
   end do

   do jj=1,ju-jl+1
     yd(jj)=(y(jj+jl-1)-y(j))**2
   end do

   do kk=1,ku-kl+1
     zd(kk)=(z(kk+kl-1)-z(k))**2
   end do

   do jj=1,ju-jl+1
     do kk=1,ku-kl+1
       do ii=1,iu-il+1
         eudist(ii,kk,jj)=xd(ii)+yd(jj)+zd(kk)
       enddo
     enddo
   enddo

   seed=sgn(i,k,j)
   tmp(i)=minval(eudist(:,1:ku-kl+1,:),seed*sgn(il:iu,kl:ku,jl:ju).le.0)
   tmp(i)=-seed*dsqrt(tmp(i))

  enddo
  dist(:,k,j)=tmp
 enddo
enddo
```

EDIT: more information on the problem at hand.
The grid is an orthogonal grid mapped to a matrix. The number of points of this grid is of the order of 1000 in each direction (in total about 1 billion points).

My goal is switching from a sign function (+1,0,-1) to a signed distance function in the entire grid in an efficient way.

Comment: The important thing is to be aware where you really need the distance and try to compute it only where it is really needed. If you really need everywhere, you do not have much choice than to compute it.

Comment: But what you could do, is to trade some memory for the CPU time and if your grid (I would avoid the word matrix) is orthogonal, you compute the `(x-xi)**2` factors for the whole plane with the same *x* coordinate, and so on. You really have to tell us more about your grid.

Comment: I actually need this distance function at each point of the grid.
I mixed grid and matrix as the grid is indeed an orthogonal grid that can be easily mapped to a matrix.

Comment: Adding on your second point, the second method calculates the distance function only within a subset of the domain, thus should be faster than computing the factors on each plane.

Comment: Who knows, you should shows us that version first.

Comment: I included also the second version in the edited post.

Comment: Wait, please show us the declarations of your variables and arrays. Especially, what is `eudist` and why do you assign an array into it? Andy please explain your other version. What is the motivation for the subset? Subset in which sense? You need to have the function everywhere, don't you?

Comment: I updated the post, hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I would still do what I suggested, no matter if you do that on a subset or across the whole plane. Take advantage of the orthogonal grid, it is a great thing to have

```
do j=1,ny
 do k=1,nz
  do i=1,nx
   ! look for closest point in box 2*deltax+1,2*deltaz+1,2*deltay+1
   il=max(1,i-deltax)
   iu=min(nx,i+deltax)
   jl=max(1,j-deltay)
   ju=min(ny,j+deltay)
   kl=max(1,k-deltaz)
   ku=min(nz,k+deltaz)


   do ii = il,iu
     xd(i) = (xyz(ii,kl:ku,jl:ju,1)-x(i))**2
   end do

   do jj = jl,ju
     yd(i) = (xyz(il:iu,kl:ku,jj,2)-y(j))**2
   end do

   do kk = kl,ku
     zd(k) = (xyz(il:iu,kk,jl:ju,3)-z(k))**2
   end do

   do jj = jl,ju
     do kk = kl,ku
       do ii = il,iu
         eudist(il:iu,kl:ku,jl:ju) = xd(ii) + yd(jj) + zd(kk)
       end do
     end do
   end do
   ....

  enddo
  dist(:,k,j)=tmp
 enddo
enddo
```

Consider separating the whole thing that is inside the outer triple loop into a subroutine or a function. It would not be faster, but it would be much more readable. Especially for us here, It would be enough for us here to only deal with that function, the outer loop is just a confusing extra layer.

Comment: I kept also the outer loop as adding further nested loops raise the computational cost: each nx,ny,nz is of the order of 1000, so 6 nested loops means 1000^6 iterations (if no subset is considered).

With your option I get a speed-up of a factor 2, which is yet not enough for me.

Comment: @Giovanni I don't get what you are saying. That should be an equivalent code refactoring, no change in the performance. Regarding the speedup, the problem is that we do not have a [mcve]. We dont even have your variable declarations, we do not know  what `tmp` is, what `posit` is, we can only guess. I expect you should get *much* larger speedup if done properly.

Comment: I am trying to simplify the code as much as possible (the version here does not consider periodicity in any direction, which is actually needed). I will edit the post to make the example clearer.
I am actually looking for any efficient way to transform a sign function to a signed distance function; I proposed a possible solution, but I am open to any other possibility that gives me a considerable speed up.

Comment: Of course you can simplify the program, notice the **minimal** in MCVE, you can make it just one function without the outer loop, but it should include everything necessary. Best, one should be able to actually run it and test the performance.

Comment: Please check the new post; I tried to include everything, this is part of a subroutine that accepts sgn as an input and gives dist as an output. To test the performances I use a timer before and after the outermost loop. sgn is a the output of a sign operation, +1, 0, -1. I tried using an integer variable (instead of double precision) but got no considerable speed up.